# infinite eject buttons appearing in menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, eject

My menu bar automatically fills in all empty space with eject buttons. How can I remedy this problem? Is it a sign of a bug?

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: What software are you running to put the first eject button in the menu bar? That's not a standard OS X control.

Comment: move the Eject.menu file from /System/Library/Core Services/Menu Extras somewhere else and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a part of the Mac O/S. Just not documented and not on all versions of the O/S. You can find out easily enough.

Navigate to

/System/Library/Core Services/Menu Extras

...and double click on Eject.menu to add the eject button (if it's there)

remove it by command-dragging it off the menu bar.

But why the menu bar fills up with eject buttons, sorry.